# ASP.NET-Identity OnModelCreating Modelbuilder Generating Duplicate Foreign Keys

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, ef-fluent-api

I have an ASP MVC 5 application but the model builder is creating duplicate foreign keys for the IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim and IdentityUserLogin tables.

E.g in the generated migration table below has RoleId as well as IdentityRole_ID

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.UserRole",
            c => new
                {
                    RoleId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    IdentityRole_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    ApplicationUser_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.RoleId, t.UserId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Role", t => t.IdentityRole_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.User", t => t.ApplicationUser_Id)
            .Index(t => t.IdentityRole_Id)
            .Index(t => t.ApplicationUser_Id);
```

In my fluent api I have this defined as follows:

```
   public IdentityUserRoleConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => new { x.RoleId, x.UserId });
        ToTable("UserRole");
    }
```

My modelbuilder class:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    // Add some DBSets      

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("ApplicationDbContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        // base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserRoleConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserLoginConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityRoleConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IdentityUserClaimConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ApplicationUserConfiguration());


    }

}
```

I've commented out the `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` statement becuase it throws the following error when I run a migration:

```
A configuration for type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserRole' has already been added. To reference the existing configuration use the Entity<T>() or ComplexType<T>() methods.
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration can be implemented as follows,

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLoginProviders");
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
    }
```

Since the fluent configuration are already implemented for most of *IdentityRole, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim, IdentityUserLogin* models in `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` Hence it allows only to override ApplicationUser. Hence the only way to implement his is like `Entity<T>()`